# Spring Integration: Define sequential handling of messages using Java DSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I can't get my head around a solution for a - as I consider - rather common integration flow:

1. read a file from source
2. process file
3. delete file from sourced **if** processing was successful.

Currently, I have an IntegrationFlow using a PublishSubscribeChannel with two IntegrationFlows as subscribers: One to process file, one to delete file. Unfortunately, the later one (delete) is executed regardless of the outcome of the first one (process), even if the "process" flow throws an Exception.

What I need is a sequential handling flow, but I cannot figure out how to realize. Created some test code, but that doesn't work, reporting

```
2022-11-22 09:55:54.256 ERROR 14648 --- [   scheduling-1]
o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   :
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to 
invoke method; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
```

The lab code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SeqChannels {

    @Bean
    public AtomicInteger integerSource() {
        return new AtomicInteger();
    }

    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "process", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public Message<Integer> source(final AtomicInteger integerSource) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(integerSource.incrementAndGet()).build();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "process", outputChannel = "delete")
    public Integer process(@Payload Integer message) {
        return message;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "delete")
    public void delete(@Payload Integer message) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Btw: It's Spring Integration 5.5

Comment: You need to show the flow configuration; by default, the second subscriber won't be called if the first one fails, but that behavior can be changed; so we need to see your flow. Also, an error message like that is useless without the full stack trace.

Comment: @GaryRussell The exception above is related to the code shown. That's a full lab example. 

Actually, it's just another desparete attempt to realize my "sequential" flow. Also tryed using PubSubChannel with 2 subscribers, but the do not depend on each other and get called regardless on any "previous" output.

Comment: One more time - please show the flow configs and the full stack trace; nobody can help you without that.

Comment: An `@InboundChannelAdapter`method must not have any parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have parameters on an `@InboundChannelAdapter` method. This works...

```java
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
class SeqChannels {

    AtomicInteger integerSource = new AtomicInteger();

    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "process", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
    public Message<Integer> source() {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(this.integerSource.incrementAndGet()).build();
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "process", outputChannel = "delete")
    public Integer process(@Payload Integer message) {
        System.out.println("Process: " + message);
        return message;
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "delete")
    public void delete(@Payload Integer message) {
        System.out.println("delete: " + message);
    }

}
```

```
Process: 1
delete: 1
Process: 2
delete: 2
Process: 3
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when implementing I cannot figure out if and how to use Spring's outbound adapters for Sftp, Jdbc and AMQP. It looks like it's either ServiceActivator or message endpoint, not both. When using ServiceActivator, I have to go done all the path using JdbcTemplate and stuff, for example.

What is the proper way to let a message be handled by multiple handlers, sequentially and aborting further processing if one handler fails?

Comment: Outbound adapters are one way, with no reply. Use a pubsub channel or recipient list router.

Comment: Thanks (again). I had the impression that pub/sub-channels are more like fan-out-queues, calling their subscribers in parallel, but now I see that they are sequential.

Comment: They are sequential, as long as you don't provide a executor.